# android ServiceConnection listener in a separate thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service

I'm trying to implement the ServiceConnection object in a separate thread, however, not sure how to keep thread alive so onServiceConnected() callback can happen accordingly.

Below is the code snippet:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    ServiceConnection con = new ServiceConnection() {
      public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        serviceObj = <AIDL Interface>.Stub.asInterface(service);
      }
      public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        serviceObj = null;
      }
  }
}).start();
```

The problem is the thread exists immediately and obviously onServiceConnected() will never get invoked that way. Any idea how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods of `ServiceConnection` will be called on the main thread, no matter where or how you create the `ServiceConnection` object. There is nothing you can do to change this behaviour.

What is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I was trying to make the service connection synchronous.

Comment: I see. Well, you can't do that. It is actually unfortunate that these callbacks come on the main thread, but that's the way it is.